# String format with Reg Ex

Tags: regex

How can I write a regular expression to match "SS19100025" type of string?

Start with 2 "S" then "191" then after 5 digit number.

Thanks a lot,
devweb

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
/SS191\d{5}/
```

**Edit**:
If you're looking to learn Regex, may I recommend [Mastering Regular Expressions](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596528126/).  It is a fantastic book and has helped me tremendously.  Also answering questions on SO is another great way to learn regex.

Comment: Will sure take a look at this book. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

this should work:

```
/^SS191[0-9]{5}$/
```

Comment: you may already know this but, you can use the \d flag in place of [0-9]

Comment: Phil's is better.  It insures that there is nothing before or after the desired string.

Answer (score 0):

You can try "SS191\d{5}"